# Mysqli Query In Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, function, mysqli

Wonder if you can help me figure this out. Latest PHP in WordPress 3.92. WordPress is using MySqli. I am trying to change my custom MYSQL to MYSQLI which should really be simple enough, but is throwing up so issues.

Below are 2 examples. Example 1 is using WordPress built in MYSQLI connection inside a function and the one underneath is my own. The first one throws up errors as shown but my own one does not.

```
function name{
global $wpdb;
$options = array();
$res=mysqli_query($wpdb,"select ID,County from counties ORDER BY County ASC");
$value="";
$label="Please select a county";
$options[] = array('label' => $label, 'value' => $value);
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($res)) {
    $sC=$row['ID'];
    $res1=mysqli_query($wpdb,"select County from wedding_shows where County='$sC'");
        if (mysqli_num_rows($res1) == 0) {
        } else {
        $options[] = array('label' => $row['County'], 'value' => $row['ID']);
        }
    }
}
```

Here are the errors i get

Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, object given eval()’d code on line 3

Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, null given eval()’d code on line 4

and here is it working with my own connection and no errors.

```
function name(
$dbhost1 = 'localhost';
$dbuser1 = 'user';
$dbpass1 = 'pass';
$dbname1 = 'DBName';
$conn=mysqli_connect($dbhost1 ,$dbuser1,$dbpass1,$dbname1);
$options = array();
$res=mysqli_query($conn,"select ID,County from counties ORDER BY County ASC");
$value="";
$label="Please select a county";
$options[] = array('label' => $label, 'value' => $value);
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($res)) {
    $sC=$row['ID'];
    $res1=mysqli_query($conn,"select County from wedding_shows where County='$sC'");
        if (mysqli_num_rows($res1) == 0) {
        } else {
        $options[] = array('label' => $row['County'], 'value' => $row['ID']);
        }
             }
}
```

I must be looking to hard as I cannot see why this would not work in the first instance to save having to create a new connection inside every function.

Many thanks
P

Comment: Why use mysqli at all?  Why not simply use the $wpdb (http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb) functions, since you have access to it and let wordpress take care of the driver implementationd etails?

Comment: @adam - wpdb returns a primitive types...not robust and complete like standard result set returned by native mysql/mysqli setup.  I'll never go to these temporary fixes that these cms/frameworks etc want the developers to use...they're horrible in scalability, complex problems, version issues, and robustness.  I urge all developers to stay way from these "theory-less" tools.  Horrible in real software development perspective.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first argument of `mysqli_query` is expected to be a mysqli connection object. `$wpdb` is not a mysqli connection object, it is the wordpress database object. That being said, you could just do `$wpdb->get_results("select ID,County from counties ORDER BY County ASC");` instead, given that the query is proper.

Comment: be aware that get_results and even wpdb->query fetches the entire results into array. something not used when dealing with large custom database.

Comment: @Dreadedsemicolon That is just entirely untrue. The size of the database does not matter when using indexes. The query arguments matter.

Comment: (Meant to say not useful instead of used). It is entirely true.  I didn't say query doesn't matter. it's just that wordpress fetches results in an array unlike the behavior of mysqli_query. look at wpdb->query method code. so if you are performing a loop on a large database say you want to convert a large table into another type. select * from mygigatable.  wordpress is going to try to place it all in one large array causing out of memory error.  Source line: 1889-1890 wordpress 5.0.3 "while ( $row = mysqli_fetch_object( $this->result ) ) {$this->last_result[$num_rows] = $row;"